# Run Django Celery Nohup in Crontab

Tags: python, django, celery, nohup

I want to run some tasks in django. I'm using Celery to do this. Usually, I run this command to execute the tasks:

```
source myvirtualenvpath/bin/activate
nohup python manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=DEBUG < /dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

I want to do this each time the machine reboot with a crontab. How can I
do this?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds more like a) a task for a start job and b) a question for a system related sibling site of SO.

Comment: Hi! Do you know how to do it?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I made that but it seems to be that the virtual env does not start

Answer (score 0):

I solved making this:

nohup path_to_virtual_env/bin/python path_to_project/manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=DEBUG < /dev/null &>/dev/null &